# "Invalid column name" while creating a dropdown with "new SelectList()"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I got the error in the title when building a simple dropdown. This is my view:

```
<td>
     <select asp-for="ThisShutdown.Id" asp-items=@(new 
          SelectList(Model.ListOfAllGGGs,"Id","Location"))>
          <option>Selelct a GGG</option>                    
     </select>  
</td>
```

**The ViewModel:**

```
public class PlannerViewModel
{
    public GGGShutdown ThisShutdown { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GGGShutdown> ExistingShutdowns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GGG> ListOfAllGGGs { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller:**

```
public class PlannerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGGGRepository _GGGRepository;
    private readonly IGGGShutdownRepository _GGGShutdownRepository;

    public PlannerController (IGGGShutdownRepository GGGShutdownRepository, IGGGRepository GGGRepository)
    {
        _GGGShutdownRepository = GGGShutdownRepository;
        _GGGRepository = GGGRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult ShowGGGShutdowns()
    {
        IEnumerable<GGGShutdown> CurrentShutdowns = _GGGShutdownRepository.GGGShutdowns;
        IEnumerable<GGG> AllGGGs = _GGGRepository.GGGs;

        PlannerViewModel MyViewModel = new PlannerViewModel();
        MyViewModel.ExistingShutdowns = CurrentShutdowns;
        MyViewModel.ListOfAllGGGs = AllGGGs;
        return View(MyViewModel);
    }
}
```

For info, this is the GGG Class, which is the one that I use to build the dropdown:

```
public class GGG
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string PlantModel { get; set; }
    public string EntrySystem { get; set; }
    public string Technology { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Can you show us the shape of your GGG table on the database please ?

Comment: Hi CodeNotFound. I'm using EF core, so the "public class GGG" code part is actually the shape of my database, isn't it? My columns are: Id, Location, Country, CustomerName, PlantModel, Entrysystem, Technology. (I'm a newbie so I may have misunderstood your question).

Comment: Your columns names are ok to me. Can you please add the full error message ? Or check the inner exception message for more information ?

Comment: Entity has to be recompiled and c# classes need to be refresh when errors like this occur.  There is an inconsistency between the c# classes and the database.

Comment: jdweng, CodeNotFound - you were right, the architecture in the SQL was different from the one locally. I solved it as following: 1) Erased the most recent Snapshot 2) Create an "add-migration new" which created the whole db 3) Comment out everything but the table GGG 4) Manually erased in DB the table GGG 5) Update-database, which re-created GGG in the Database... I'm still testing so the data inside wasn't that important, but I wonder what coudl I have done if i didn't want to lose the data in GGG. EF doesn't seem to be very reliable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "invalid column name" error is almost invariably due to your entity being out of sync with the table that represents it in your database. You might have renamed a property, added a new property, etc. and neglected to generate a new migration. Or if you're using an existing database, you may need to rescaffold your entities from your database again. In any case, either `Id` or `Location` does not match up with an actual column on your table. Figure out why, and your problem is solved.

Comment: As commented beefore: yes, indeed; the architecture in the SQL was different from the one locally. I solved it as following: 1) Erased the most recent Snapshot 2) Create an "add-migration new" which created the whole db 3) Comment out everything but the table GGG 4) Manually erased in DB the table GGG 5) Update-database, which re-created GGG in the Database... I'm still testing so the data inside wasn't that important, but I wonder what coudl I have done if i didn't want to lose the data in GGG. EF doesn't seem to be very reliable

Comment: You shouldn't have removed the snapshot. When you make changes to your entities, you just generate a new migration, and it applies the schema changes necessary to match the entity.